# For check box, ng-dropdown-multiselect work with ng-disabled in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using **ng-dropdown-multiselect for checkboxes in angularjs and html**. With this ng-disabled work or not?.

**If i selected only one particular checkbox remaining all checkboxes have to disable. I selected particular 6th one then only remaining all checkboxes have to disable. send those label names to server like ques and ans format.**

Please give me answer.Thank you.

```
<div class="form-group">
<span class="downArow icon-ArrowDown org fnt12"> </span>
<label for="name" class="blu" ng-init="task.formObj[27].ques='Is there any observation you wish to bring attention to?'"
```

ng-model="task.formObj[27].ques">Is there any observation you wish to bring attention to?

**JS FILE CONTAINS**

```
self.options = [{'family_banking': [{id: 1, label: "Spouse"}, {id: 2, label: "Father"}, {id: 3, label: "Mother"},{id: 4, label: "Childern (Staying together)"},{id: 5, label: "Brother/Sister"}]},
                            {'attachments':[{id: 1, label: "Mera iMobile"},{id: 2, label: "ECS/ADM"},{id: 3, label: "PPF"},{id: 4, label: "FD/RD"},{id: 5, label: "LI"},{id: 6, label: "SIP"},{id: 7, label: "Other"}]},
                            {'p2c':[{id: 1, label: "SA"},{id: 2, label: "CA"},{id: 3, label: "KCC"},{id: 4, label: "JL"},{id: 5, label: "RBC"},{id: 6, label: "FE"},{id: 7, label: "FD/RD"},{id: 8, label: "LI"},{id: 9, label: "Other"}]},
                            {'special_task':[{id: 1, label: "Gold Loan"},{id: 2, label: "KCC"},{id: 3, label: "FE"},{id: 4, label: "SHG"},{id: 5, label: "RBC"},{id: 6, label: "CBF"},{id: 7, label: "Savings Account"},{id: 8, label: "Current Account"},{id: 9, label: "Mutual Fund"},{id: 10, label: "Insurance"},{id: 11, label: "Other"}]},
                            {'observations':[{id: 1, label: "Suspected fraud"},{id: 2, label: "End use violation"},{id: 3, label: "Fields destroyed due to natural calamity"},{id: 4, label: "Customer is  in financial stress"},{id: 5, label: "Any criminal case against  applicant / co-applicant reported"},{id: 6, label: "Any additional critical information"},{id: 7, label: "No Observation"}]},
                            {'reasons':[{id:1,label:"Better offer from Comp Bank"},{id:2,label:"Offer not appealing"},{id:3,label:"Charges Levied"},{id:4,label:"Service Issues"},{id:5,label:"Other"}]},
              {'reasons1':[{id:1,label:"Custom hiring for agri"},{id:2,label:"Own field"},{id:3,label:"Commercial"}]}];
```